# Linux : install mysql-client after Zimbra

Tags: mysql, linux, configuration, zimbra

I installed Zimbra on my Linux server (Ubuntu 12.04 x64), and now I have to install mysql-client / mysql-server for other things.

During Zimbra install, it install mysql (in /opt/zimbra/mysql). This mysql server listen on port 7301.

Can I install mysql on my Linux without breaking my Zimbra install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested. No problem. The MySql server of Zimbra is completely independent of the system.

Answer (score 0):

Zimbra uses mysql/mariadb for storing the metadata.

The Data Store is a MariaDB database where internal mailbox IDs are linked 
with user accounts. All the message metadata including tags, conversations, 
and pointers indicate where the messages are stored in the file system. The 
MariaDB database files are in /opt/zimbra/db

Reference; https://files.zimbra.com/website/docs/8.6/Zimbra_NE_Admin_Guide_8.6.0.pdf